# Linq to Entities - using group by for many-to-many tables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I would appreciate any assistance in determining the proper way to utilize Linq to Entities for my application. Specifically, when working with multiple many-to-many tables, I am having difficulty understanding grouping.

The simplified database design is:

http://imageshack.us/a/img443/5863/entitydesignerdiagram.png

DB Design Concept:

People: individual people that have access to edit multiple statistics.
Seasons: Time period to group statistics by, such as 2012 baseball, or 2012 .
Players: individual or gorup of people involved in the statistic. All that is needed here is a name for the entity. Such as Kevin Wasie, or Varsity Team
Statistics: Holds individual statistic information belonging to 1 season, such as Touchdowns, or Home-Runs.

Code Behind:

```
    Dim stats = From st In pl.statistics From per In st.people
      Where per.id.Equals(personID)
      Select New With
            {.season_name = st.season.name, .statistic_name = st.name, .season_id = st.season.id,
             .players = From play In pl.players
                             Where play.seasonId = st.season.id
                             Select New With {.player_name = play.name}}

    rep_statistics.DataSource = stats
    rep_statistics.DataBind()
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_actions" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<b><%# Eval("season_name")%></b> - <%# Eval("statistic_name")%><br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="rep_part" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("players")%>'>
    <itemtemplate>
    <%# Eval("participantname")%>
    </itemtemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>,</SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The desired outcome is to have the page displayed grouped by the season as such:

```
Season 1
   Statistic 1
      Season1 Players
   Statistic 2
      Season1 Players
   Statistic 3
      Season1 Players
Season 2
   Statistic 4
      Season 2 Players
...
```

The current outcome is:

```
Season 1
   Statistic 1
      Season1 Players
Season 1
   Statistic 2
      Season1 Players
Season 1
   Statistic 3
      Season1 Players
Season 2
   Statistic 4
      Season 2 Players
...
```

How do I modify the linq to get the desired outcome?

Any assistance, including links to tutorials or other information, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the result now. Anyway, the db structure doesn't look good. There should be a direct relation between person and player.

Comment: The result right now is: Season1/Statistic1/Season1Players > Season1/Statistic2/Season1Players ... I would like it to be Season1/Statitic1/Season1Players > Statistic2/Season1Players, etc... 

DB design: Players and people are two different things: Players can be individual people, or teams, so all that is needed for the players table is a name of the entity involved in that season. The people table are individual people that have access to multiple statistics to edit. I do have a demographics table in the actual design to hold demographic data, but left it out here for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is C# code, but I hope it will give you a hint on what you need to do. 
The query filters the people with the given `Id` and uses `SelectMany()` to select the statistics for those persons.

Afterwards, it groups the selected statistics by `SeasonId` and populates the collection of the seasons to be outputed.

```
var data = st.People
             .Where(p => p.Id == personID)
             .SelectMany(p => p.Statistics)
             .GroupBy(s => s.SeasonId)
             .Select(g => new
             {
                 SeasonId = g.Key,
                 SeasonName = g.Fist().Season.Name,
                 Statistics = g.Select(s => new
                               {
                                   StatisticId = s.Id,
                                   StatisticName = s.Name,
                                   Players = s.Season.Players
                               })
             });
```

Comment: Thank you! One more caveat to it: I am trying to access the columns of Players like  `code` Key .Players= s.[Select](Function(k) New With {Key .PlayerName = s.Season.Player.Name `code` This does not work, as I get the error: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments" Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: `Select` method can be applied to collections. `s` is a single item.